# Positive integer solutions to $pxy+x+y=p\#$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, prime-factorization

Let $p$ be prime and $p{\#}$ the product of all primes not larger than $p$. Are there any positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $pxy+x+y=p{\#}$. It appears there are no solutions. There are no solutions with $p<200$. Can it be shown that this is the case for all primes $p$?

My thoughts:  Let $n=pxy+x+y$. If we can show that if $q \ | \ n$ for all primes $q \le p$ and $q\nmid  n$ for all primes $q>p$ then $q^2 \ | \ n$ for some prime $q \le p$, then we are done. (Note: The proposition is false for higher powers of $p{\#}$. It's also false when $p{\#}$ is replaced by $p!$ , or $p{\#} + b, b \not = 0$)

Comment: It might help to note that the greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$ is square-free. Also if $q \ | \ x$ and $q \le p$ then $q \ | \ y$ and if $q \ | \ x$ and $q >p$ then $q \nmid y$

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are allowed to be negative, many solutions exist.

Comment: Also it appears there are no solutions in $ x>0, y>0 $ when $ p^{#} $ is replaced by $ p^{#}/p $.

Comment: The usual notation for the product of all primes not larger than $p$ is just "$p$#" , this is called a primorial. What might help : $pxy+x+y=p$# is equivalen to $(px+1)(py+1)=p\cdot p$#$+1$

Comment: How did you make sure that there are no solutions for $p<200$ ?

Comment: I ran a maple script

Comment: $199$# is very large. Did you use the prime factorizations to verify whether there are solutions ? I ask because I see no other way.

Comment: I used the code isolve(pxy+x+y=p#) and iterated through the primes. The product p# was obtained using the code n = n * p.  Of course I  had to wait for some 5 to 10 mins for the computation to complete. p# grows rapidly

Comment: OK, I just wanted to clarify that. For a counterexample, a semiprime with prime factors of the form $kp+1$ would be enough. But it is far from clear whether such a semiprime exists.

Comment: Exist solution $(p,x,y)=$`(487,4,261446349442939643115460323046104554381307628716846932424861892280240246672326712119969908349883438693494715115284175656617820027508900420741693544250639794918736490544582819298886730792180963062094)`

Comment: Its amazing how difficult it is to find a pattern in primes! Since there's one solution, most likely infinitely many of them exist. Is it possible to construct an efficient algorithm that checks if a solution exists for a particular prime $p$?

Comment: @DavidJones No, it isn't. We have to factor the expression, otherwise we won't be able to rule out a solution. And the primes contain no "pattern" in the sense that we cannot "construct" efficiently any huge prime that is not already known.

Comment: Alright. I am searching for forms of integers $a$ that don't require factorization in order to decide if the diophantine equation $pxy +x + y=a$ has any solutions in positive integers $x,y$ for a given prime $p$. If $p >a^{1/4}$ , there's an efficient way to compute all solutions of $pxy +x + y=a$ without factoring . If $p >a^{1/3}$,  all solutions can be obtained in a single multiplication and substitution. These solutions don't require $p$ to be prime. So I thought $a = p\#$ , $p$ prime would be a possible candidate but turns out its not$.